# How to use MySQL with conda/Python 3.6

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

I'm trying to use Python with MySQL, following an online tutorial. In the tutorial he installs mysql on Ubuntu, I'm using Windows with Anaconda. 
I just want start mysql, with the basic command "mysql -u root -p", which I assume is the same on conda.

I've installed MySQL by downloading it and going through the easy installer (MySQL Workbench works). I've installed "mysqlclient" using pip. I've installed "pymysql" and "mysql-connector-python" using conda.

I still am not able to start up mysql through conda. I have some experience with MySQL, am new to Python and Anaconda.

I have Python 3.6 installed, MySQL 5.6, Windows 10.
Right now when I try to start mysql through Anaconda (>mysql) it just says "mysql is not recognized..."

I'm assuming I can use Conda just like terminal in Linux to enter MySQL.

In this question [How to use MySQL with Anaconda's Python IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228687/how-to-use-mysql-with-anacondas-python-ide) someone answered by downloading "pymysql" which I've done. Is there more to it than just installing it?

Comment: It is a bit offtopic, but you can probably make your life a bit easier if you use a package like http://www.wampserver.com/en/
It comes with Apache, MySQL and PHP, and a nice UI that you can use to manage mysql and its modules.

Apache and PHP might come as overhead, but they provide environment to run PhpMyAdmin, which is part of the WAMP and a great tool to manage local MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into the same issue. First of all I had to go into Task Manager > Services, and switch mysql to "running".
Then all I had to do was navigate to the mysql folder with conda and was able to start mysql from there.